# In pandas, how to concatenate some dataframes to get a single dataframe with an additional column that keeps track of the original dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to concatenate some dataframe and get a resultant dataframe where and additional column gives me information about the original dataframe.

With this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']},
index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A4', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7'],
'B': ['B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'],
'C': ['C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7'],
'D': ['D4', 'D5', 'D6', 'D7']},
index=[4, 5, 6, 7])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A8', 'A9', 'A10', 'A11'],
'B': ['B8', 'B9', 'B10', 'B11'],
'C': ['C8', 'C9', 'C10', 'C11'],
'D': ['D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'D11']},
index=[8, 9, 10, 11])

frames = [df1, df2, df3]

result = pd.concat(frames,keys=['df1','df2','df3'])

print(result)
```

I get this result with a hierarchical row index.

```
          A    B    C    D
df1 0    A0   B0   C0   D0
    1    A1   B1   C1   D1
    2    A2   B2   C2   D2
    3    A3   B3   C3   D3
df2 4    A4   B4   C4   D4
    5    A5   B5   C5   D5
    6    A6   B6   C6   D6
    7    A7   B7   C7   D7
df3 8    A8   B8   C8   D8
    9    A9   B9   C9   D9
    10  A10  B10  C10  D10
    11  A11  B11  C11  D11
```

Instead I would like to get this result:

```
       A    B    C    D    src
 0    A0   B0   C0   D0    df1
 1    A1   B1   C1   D1    df1
 2    A2   B2   C2   D2    df1
 3    A3   B3   C3   D3    df1
 4    A4   B4   C4   D4    df2
 5    A5   B5   C5   D5    df2
 6    A6   B6   C6   D6    df2
 7    A7   B7   C7   D7    df2
 8    A8   B8   C8   D8    df3
 9    A9   B9   C9   D9    df3
10   A10  B10  C10  D10    df3
11   A11  B11  C11  D11    df3
```

I had a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html but I can't find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from your result, you can [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get the first level index as a new column:

```
(pd.concat(frames,keys=['df1','df2','df3'])
   .rename_axis(['src',None])
   .reset_index(level=0))

    src    A    B    C    D
0   df1   A0   B0   C0   D0
1   df1   A1   B1   C1   D1
2   df1   A2   B2   C2   D2
3   df1   A3   B3   C3   D3
4   df2   A4   B4   C4   D4
5   df2   A5   B5   C5   D5
6   df2   A6   B6   C6   D6
7   df2   A7   B7   C7   D7
8   df3   A8   B8   C8   D8
9   df3   A9   B9   C9   D9
10  df3  A10  B10  C10  D10
11  df3  A11  B11  C11  D11
```

Answer (score 1):

```
frames = [df1, df2, df3]

for i in range(len(frames)):
    frames[i]['src'] = "df"+str(i+1)
# result = pd.concat(frames,keys=['df1','df2','df3'])
result = pd.concat(frames)

print(result)
```

```
      A    B    C    D  src
0    A0   B0   C0   D0  df1
1    A1   B1   C1   D1  df1
2    A2   B2   C2   D2  df1
3    A3   B3   C3   D3  df1
4    A4   B4   C4   D4  df2
5    A5   B5   C5   D5  df2
6    A6   B6   C6   D6  df2
7    A7   B7   C7   D7  df2
8    A8   B8   C8   D8  df3
9    A9   B9   C9   D9  df3
10  A10  B10  C10  D10  df3
11  A11  B11  C11  D11  df3
```